# За что отвечает ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-manifest

Добрый день уважаемые! В манивесте приложения содержится следующее разрешение :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Не могу найти информации простым языком о том, за что оно отвечает. Понял что это разрешение позволяет приложению менять GPS данные и это как то связано с locale. Может кто то обьяснить подробнее ?

Comment: ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION позволяет создавать фиктивные местоположения.

Comment: @lampa я тестировал приложения на 2х разных устройствах. одно работало успешно, второе выдало исключение и попросило `Add the permission 'android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION' to your manifest`

Comment: @Сергей, учтите, что данное разрешение было убрано начиная с версии API 23. Так что могу предположить, что устройство, на котором падали исключения, работало на Android 6.0+

Comment: @A.Shakhov тогда понятно, почему на у-ве с ОС 5.1.1 выпало исключение а на 6.0.1 нет.  Но зачем вообще создавайть ложную GPS ?

Comment: @Сергей написал в ответе

Comment: @A.Shakhov `В основном, это требуется для тестирования` можно подробнее  ?

Comment: @Сергей, в ответе есть ссылка с примером, лично я не применял это для тестов кода работы с GPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, позволяет mock'ать данные местоположения, то есть подставлять фейковые данные GPS. В основном, это требуется для тестирования.

Comment: Теперь сайт не работает.

Comment: @CoolMind спасибо, убрал ссылку. Уже не помню, что там было 5 лет назад

Comment: Пожалуйста! Думаю, кто будет искать, легко найдёт кучу материалов. Тоже недавно работал с этой темой, пришлось подключать библиотеку для UI-тестирования координат. В манифесте это разрешение тоже прописывал.